# Downloaded xcode 8.1 on Sierra, it still says I have 8.0 installed?

Tags: xcode, python-3.x, app-store, homebrew

I'm trying to install python3 with brew. I am unable to as it says I have 8.0 installed, even though in the app store it says I installed 8.1. Also, when I open xcode, it says I have Version 8.0 (8A218a) installed.

This is what I did:

```
   $ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   $ brew update

$ brew install python3 
Error: Your Xcode (8.0) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 8.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

This is the guide I am following : http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/29/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-osx/

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue when trying to brew install imagemagick earlier today.

xcode showed version 8.0, but the app store thought I was up to date (ie was running 8.1). I 'fixed' it by deleting xcode and triggering a reinstall via the app store.

Comment: An alternative would be to download the `.tar` file from their website (this is what I ended up doing)